# Interchange intersection and union in proof of Blumenthal’s zero-one law

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, brownian-motion

I am trying to prove Blumenthal's zero-one law using Kolmogorov's zero-one law. I use that $B_t$ Brownian $\iff$ $tB_{1/t}$ Brownian. Can I change the intersection and union as follows?

*Start of my proof*

If $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion then $(B_t^*)_{t\geq 0}:=(tB_\frac{1}{t})_{t\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion.
We have 
$$\mathcal{F}_{0+}^B=\cap_{t>0}\mathcal{F}_t^B=\cap_{t>0}\sigma(B_s:s\leq t)
.$$
For any event in this $\sigma$-algebra there must also exist an event in $\mathcal{F}_{0+}^{B^*}$ with the same probability. But
\begin{align*}\mathcal{F}_{0+}^{B^*}&=\cap_{t>0}\mathcal{F}_t^{B^*}=\cap_{t>0}\sigma(B_s^*:s\leq t)=\cap_{t>0}\sigma(sB_\frac{1}{s}:s\leq t)=\cap_{t>0}\sigma(B_s:s>t)\\
&=
\cap_{t\in\mathbb{N}}\sigma(B_s:s\geq t)
=
\cap_{t\in\mathbb{N}}\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
\sigma(\sigma(B_t),\sigma(B_{t+k2^{-n}}-B_{t+(k-1)2^{-n}}:k\in\mathbb{N}))\\
&=
\cap_{t\in\mathbb{N}}\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
\sigma(B_{t+k2^{-n}}-B_{t+(k-1)2^{-n}}:k\in\mathbb{N})\\
&=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\cap_{t\in\mathbb{N}}
\sigma(B_{t+k2^{-n}}-B_{t+(k-1)2^{-n}}:k\in\mathbb{N})
\end{align*}
By application of Komogorov's zero-one law we see that all events in the latter set must have either probability one or zero. QED.